# Is the supremum of a subset of functions element of the larger set?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I tried to prove the following statement and would like to know whether my proof contains errors. Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ and let $\geq$ be a relation defined as for any two $f,f'  \in X: f \geq f' $ if $f(y) \geq f'(y) \ \forall y \in [0,1] $.

The statement I want to proof is:

**Proposition:** Let $(X,\geq)$ be defined as above. There exists an $S \in 2^{X} \setminus \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ which has a $\geq $ upper bound in $X$ but $\sup_{\geq} \left\lbrace S \right\rbrace \not \in X$, with $\sup$ being the smallest element of all upper bounds of $S$.

**Proof** Define $S = \left\lbrace \left\lbrace f_n \right\rbrace_{n=0}^{\infty} \in X, \ \forall n \in \mathbf{N}  \right\rbrace $, with 
\begin{equation} f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < \underline{x} \\
\dfrac{b}{\bar{x}_n - \underline{x}  }(x - \underline{x})  & \text{if } \underline{x} \leq x \leq \bar{x}_{n} \\
b  & \text{if } x> \bar{x}_n 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $0 < \underline{x} < \bar{x}_{0} < 1 $ and $\bar{x}_{n} = \underline{x} + \dfrac{\bar{x}_{n-1} - \underline{x}}{2}$ and $b \in [0,1]$.  As graphical illustration, think of a function that is constant zero or b for all $x \not \in [\underline{x},\bar{x}_{n}]$ and has a linear slope in between. One upper bound for this function is $g(y) = b \ \forall y  \in [0,1] $.  The limit of this function is:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} x < \underline{x}\\
b & \text{if} x \geq \underline{x}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This function  is not continuous and thus not element of $X$.

Can somebody kindly tell me whether the proof I do is correct?

Comment: As a first observation, you shouldn't write "Let $(X, \geq)$ be a partially ordered set", but rather "Let $(X, \geq)$ be defined as above"; otherwise it looks like you're referring to any partially ordered set, when the result does not hold.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Are you trying to show that the pointwise $\sup$ is not in the set?

Comment: The notation is somewhat confusing, which makes the proof verification difficult. I suggest you remove the underlines and overlines and simply denote $\underline{x}$ as $\alpha$ and $\bar{x}_n$ as $x_n$. Additionally, I should also point out that $f_n(x) = 1 - x^n$ yields a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but let me suggest a way to make it more readable:

Let $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$ and consider the sequence given by $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{ a_n + \alpha}{2}$, so that $a_n \searrow \alpha$. Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ given by
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &x \leq \alpha; \\
\beta \frac{x - \alpha}{a_n - \alpha}, &\alpha < x  \leq a_n;\\
\beta, &x > a_n.\end{cases} $$

This sequence is clearly increasing, but 
$$\left(\sup_{\geq} f_n\right)(x) = \begin{cases}0, &x \leq \alpha;\\
\beta, &x > \alpha \end{cases}$$
is not a continuouns function.

P.S. Since $\max X \in X$, every subset of $X$ has an upper bound.